# Installing OpenSSL on CentOS vagrant box gives 404 error

Tags: centos, openssl, vagrant

I'm running a CentOS 6 vagrant virtual machine under VMWare Fusion. The machine is working well. I need to test LDAP over SSL which requires me to install OpenSSL, so I ran `sudo yum install openssl` and I get the following errors:

```
http://mirror5.layerjet.com/remi/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [
Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2a01:4f8:11a:b1f::1: Network is
 unreachable"
Trying other mirror.

http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/extras/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYC
URL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: repoforg
eextras. Please verify its path and try again
```

Googling this error led me to try and clear the metadata cache with `sudo yum clean metadata` and `sudo yum clean all`, both of which evidently work but when I try and install OpenSSL I get the same errors.

Comment: Were you able to testing things with IPv6 disabled?

Comment: how old is your `remi.repo` file? it maybe you have out of date links. Also `openssl` is provided via the `updates` repo so you might want to try add that instead

Comment: @jww I disabled IPv6 and get the same errors.

Comment: @user3788685 I'm just using yum install, so I'm not sure how to either find out the age of remi.repo or use a different repo.

Comment: have a look at the following path `/etc/yum.repos.d/` you find all the repos listed in that folder - let me know what you have & i should be able to point you in the right direction

Comment: Ahh, found it - I do have updates.repo there as well as remi.repo both of which show a Jan 28 2016 date.  Here's the full list: http://pastebin.com/1axBQrPE

Comment: is the updates repo enabled? `enabled=1`  I get offered `openssl-1.0.1e-48.el6_8.3` it maybe there is/was an issue with the remi repo. try and disable it, do a `yum clean all` and try again with remi disabled

Comment: I did `yum repolist enabled` and, while I got the same errors above, remi came back in the enabled list.  I then tried `yum --disablerepo=remi` which did nothing and so I tried `yum --disablerepo=remi.repo` and got the error "repository not found."